# detect an string contains html or not yii2

Tags: php, regex, validation, yii2

I have an input with type of string in yii2. I want to detect that sent string to see if it contains HTML or not, then **prevent** the user from entering HTML tags.
Is there a validator including client-side validator in yii2?

**Edit**

How about an efficient regex for detecting script tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 hours continues work, I have found a solution with custom validator. here is my solution to this problem:

```
<?php
/**
 * User: Behzad
 * Date: 1/10/2016
 * Time: 6:31 PM
 */
namespace app\components;

use yii\validators\Validator;

class NoScriptValidator extends Validator
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->message = 'لطفا رشته صحیح وارد نمایید';
    }

    public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute)
    {
        $value = $model->$attribute;
        if (strpos($value, '<script') !== false) {
            $model->addError($attribute, $this->message);
        }
    }

    public function clientValidateAttribute($model, $attribute, $view)
    {
        $message = json_encode($this->message, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        return <<<JS
if(value.indexOf("<script") >= 0){
    messages.push($message);
}
JS;
    }
}
?>
```

and here is my model's rule function:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['title', 'language_id', 'project_type_id', 'text_type_id', 'description', 'deadline_day', 'deadline_time', 'doing_way_id', 'pawn_money', 'project_status', 'offerer_id', 'creation_date'], 'required'],
            [['language_id', 'project_type_id', 'text_type_id', 'pages', 'deadline_day', 'deadline_time', 'doing_way_id', 'user_id', 'pawn_money', 'project_status', 'offerer_id', 'creation_date'], 'integer'],
            [['is_group'], 'boolean'],
            [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
            [['description'], 'string', 'max' => 1024],
            [['file', 'template'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            ['title', NoScriptValidator::className()],
            ['proj_file', 'file', 'extensions' => ['zip', 'rar', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'jpg', 'png'], 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 2],
            ['doc_template', 'file', 'extensions' => ['zip', 'rar', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'xls', 'xlsx'], 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 2],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not for inspecting but for manage properly  that an input don't create damange when contain improper html tag you can use

```
Html::encode(...)
```

eg:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;

Html::encode($your_input);
```

This prevent malicious input like this

```
$myString= "<script>alert('just a test for malicius code')</script>";
```

in case of a simple

```
echo $myString;
```

you see  an alert from javascript...

with

```
echo Html::encode($myString);
```

you see the encoded string **`<script>alert('just a test for malicius code')</script>`**

Otherways you can try with regex the simplest way is testing for `'<..> ...</..>'`  but nested tag and not well formatted tag are always a problem  .[.see this doc for more detail](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/25/usingregularexpressionstomatchhtml.aspx/)

Comment: Thank you for response, Is there an efficient way to control this with regex?